# Number() defaults to 0 if null or empty

Tags: javascript

I am using the `Number()` constructor to convert strings to numbers, regardless of if they are ints or floats, but I detected a "bug" in my code where empty values were explicitly being set to `0`. Eventually I discovered that `Number()` defaults to 0 during string conversion if the string is empty or null is passed in, and while I'll probably just wrap it with a conditional to check for this, the fact that `Number()` does that didn't seem very "Javascript" behavior.

I am wondering if the problems that could be caused by this default behavior was considered when the constructor was created as I would assume there would be a more direct solution if it was, and if so does anyone know what that might be, perhaps a method that I haven't found yet?

---

To be clear, this is an easy problem to work around, be it with a conditional or by using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` but the question isn't aimed at finding an alternative solution, it is asking if a method or built in solution exists.

There are differences between say `parseFloat` and `Number` that could have additional consequences, such as `parseFloat` returning 1 instead of NaN for input `1a` or if someone wanted to pass in hexadecimal values.

More importantly this default behavior can have some considerable consequences. In example, let's say I wanted to let a user define a character limit. They decide not to fill out this optional input, but in the code I am using Number, it now defaults to 0. Any validation built using that would now fail the second anyone exceeded a character count of 0. Pretty weird to set a default, especially 0 in my opinion. Sure I could (and would) just check that the input had value, or any other of the number of solutions, and my testing would quite easily catch this, but to go that far seems fragile and unintuitive.

Comment: parseInt and parseFloat also exist.  This is a matter of opinion.  If we are talking on terms of opinion, it's very "Javascripty" with all the automatic type coercion and "truthy" values  Javascript does, which is admittedly often confusing and the subject of a lot of criticism of design choice.

Comment: It's as much _"Javascript behavior"_ as it can be -> https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-number-constructor

Comment: @user120242 usually parseFloat is fine, but in this case (and I'm sure other cases) `Number` is preferred; my preference right now is because of it returning `NaN` for anything else being passed in (ex: 2a would not return `2` as parseFloat would do) though I could create a catch for that as well. It's not that I can't easily make either work, it's that it seemed very strange for this to be an issue without a method as a solution, but I haven't found one. Call it curiosity.

Comment: There's probably a good form validation library that will do this for you.  As far as your comments on the design choice of the number coercion, the Javascript language itself in handling (loose) types shouldn't be concerned directly with form validation use cases, but rather how best to coerce values so that they stay consistent with their use within the syntax, for example with truthy/falsey values and "preferring having a usable value".  Note that this is, as you can probably see, arguably just an opinion on design choice.  But there are plenty cases where the default behavior is preferable

Comment: @user120242 Yes, I can imagine validation wouldn't be their first priority, but I guess I just have a different opinion of what assumptions should be made, I would have preferred `NaN` myself, firstly because null or an empty string is not a number, it is not the same thing as 0 in the context of numbers, though I can see the truthy/falsey aspect here where they are the same. I was stuck on the idea of dealing with numbers, and still feel that is what is intuitive over truthy/falsey, but your comment shed some light for me on why it does what it does.

Comment: Oh and about the downvotes.  It's probably due to SO policy of avoiding opinionated and debate-like discussion topics without concrete answers.  I wouldn't worry too much about it.  It's just a way to flag questions and topics that are good fit/quality and not.

Comment: Fair, I suppose the answer turned out to be opinionated, should it be truthy/falsey or handled as a number, but obviously asking the question I didn't know this would turn out to be the case, I simply thought "null or an empty string aren't the number 0 so why would it do that and does a built in solution exist"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a fairly typical problem with type conversion in javascript. Blank strings, 0, and false are all considered 'falsey' values, when you use type conversion. If you'd like the number to be converted from a blank string to NaN instead, you can use `parseFloat('', 10)`. parseFloat is cannonical way to convert a string into a number in Javascript.

Comment: In my conversation with @user120242 in the comments this turned out to be exactly what is going on, I assumed I should be working with numbers, and null and an empty string are not equal to 0; looking at it as truthy/falsey makes sense for the output to be 0.